# Pest doesn't parse a recursive grammar as I would expect

Tags: parsing, rust, pest

I'm using the [pest](https://pest.rs/) crate to implement a recursive grammar in Rust:

```
id = _{ ASCII_ALPHA_LOWER ~ (ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC|"_")* }
integer = _{ (ASCII_NONZERO_DIGIT ~ ASCII_DIGIT*)|"0" }
real = _{ ((integer ~ "." ~ ASCII_DIGIT*) | (integer? ~ "." ~ ASCII_DIGIT+)) ~ (("e"|"E") ~ ("-"|"+")? ~ ASCII_DIGIT+)? }

unaryop = _{ "sin"|"cos"|"tan"|"exp"|"ln"|"sqrt" }

inner_exp = _{ real|integer|"pi"|id }

exp = { SOI ~ ( inner_exp | (exp ~ ( "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"^" ) ~ inner_exp) | ("-" ~ exp) | ("(" ~ exp ~ ")") | (unaryop ~ "(" ~ exp ~ ")") ) ~ EOI }
```

However, I'm finding that pest isn't parsing the grammar as I would expect. For instance, `2+3` gives me an error of:

```
 --> 1:2
  |
1 | 2+3
  |  ^---
  |
  = expected EOI
```

It appears that the `inner_exp` choice is being parsed and then, when the `+` symbol is encountered, the parser doesn't know what to do. I'm pretty sure there's a problem with how I've written the `exp ~ ( "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"^" ) ~ inner_exp` choice but I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem. If I replace that choice with `exp ~ ( "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"^" ) ~ exp` I get an error stating that the expression is left-recursive. How do I fix this grammar?

Comment: I have no direct experience with this particular grammar definition language, but usually, if the parser can match the input to an alternative - `inner_exp` in this case - it will not go on to try any of the others, even if the parse fails after the current production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice operator in PEGs is ordered and works as follows: Given `e = {alt1 | alt2}`:

- If `alt1` can be matched successfully, `alt1` is applied and `alt2` is never tried.
- Otherwise `alt2` is matched
- If `alt2` can't match either, `e` fails to match

Now `e = {e1 ~ e2}` works as follows:

- If `e1` can be matched and `e2` can be matched after it, both are matched sequentially.
- Otherwise `e` fails to match.

So if you have something like `e = {(e1 | e2) ~ e3}`, the following will happen:

- If `e1` can be matched:

  - If `e3` can be matched after `e1`, both are matched sequentially
  - Otherwise, `e` fails to match
- If `e1` fails to match, but `e2` can be matched:

  - If `e3` can be matched after `e2`, both are matched sequentially
  - Otherwise, `e` fails to match

Notably if `e1` succeeds and `e3` fails, it does not go back and try to match `e2` instead. So if both `e1` and `e2` can produce a match, but only `e2` allows `e3` to be matched afterwards, `(e1 | e2) ~ e3` will fail whereas `(e1 ~ e3) | (e2 ~ e3)` would succeed.

So in your grammar you have `(inner_exp | ...) ~ EOI`. Now for your input `inner_exp` produces a match, so per the above rules the other alternatives are never tried and it tries to match `EOI` next. `EOI` doesn't match, so the whole rule fails and you get the syntax error you get.

This explains the syntax error, but it's not the only problem your grammar has:

Your `exp` rule is recursive, but it's anchored via `SOI` and `EOI`, so it can never match anything other than the entire input. This means that the recursive calls will necessarily always fail. To fix this you should remove `SOI` and `EOI` from the definition of `exp` and instead have a main rule like `start = {SOI ~ exp ~ EOI}`.

Once you've done this, you'll get an error that your `exp` rule is now left-recursive, which pest does not support. To fix that, you can replace the left recursion with repetition like this (replacing both the `inner_exp` and `exp ~ (...) ~ inner_exp` alternatives) where `operand` is a rule that matches the constructs other than infix operations:

```
operand ~ (( "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"^") ~ operand)*
```

Incidentally this will also fix your current issue because you now no longer have an `inner_exp` alternative that's tried before the alternative for infix expressions.

Your last issue is that you're not taking operator precedence into account at all. You can fix that by introducing additional "levels" of expressions in addition to `inner_exp` and `exp`, so that only operators that have the same precedence are defined in the same rule and then each rule invokes the rule containing the next higher precedence to parse the operands. That would look like this:

```
exp = { summand ~ (("+" | "-") ~ summand)* }
summand = { factor ~ (("*" | "/" | "%") ~ factor)* }
factor = { unary ~ ("^" ~ unary)* }
unary = { "-" ~ unary | unaryop ~ "(" ~ exp ~ ")" | primary }
primary = { "(" ~ exp ~ ")" | real | integer | "pi" | id }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for this answer. You've adroitly pointed out several of the issues I overlooked in my grammar. However, your answer does have an issue. To exemplify, `ln(4+4)+4*1` will fail the grammar you have suggested because `unaryop ~ "(" ~ exp ~ ")"` does not fit into `inner_exp`. Using your suggestions, I have fixed my grammer. How does [this](https://pest-parser.github.io/?bin=14pli9#editor) look?

Comment: @Woody1193 Sorry, see my edit. Your grammar leads to a weird precedence. For example `-3+4` would be parsed as `-(3+4)` rather than `(-3)+4`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. That was also a mistake on my part

Comment: I also noticed that the parser has trouble parsing `(2+3)+4` or things like that so I made an additional update: [here](https://pest-parser.github.io/?bin=718j3#editor).